# jQuery hover triggering on application start with mouse outside browser

Tags: jquery, hover, mouse, mouse-position

I have an element on the upper-left corner of the page that shows a menu when you hover over it. If you visit the page with the mouse completely outside the browser, the menu shows. As soon as you enter the browser it disappears.

My assumption is that the mouse position defaults to (0, 0) if you do not start inside the browser, and since this position is over my element, it triggers the hover. I confirmed this by moving the element one pixel to the right or one pixel down, and both behaved as expected with no initial hover.

Is there a "right" way to account for this?

**UPDATE:** Here's the jQuery code:

```
        // Enable the user menu
        $("#user")
            .hover(
                function() {
                    $("span", "#user").css("color", "#195d43");
                    $("div", "#user").show();
                },
                function() {
                    $("span", "#user").css("color", "Silver");
                    $("div", "#user").hide();
                }
        );
```

and the element:

```
<div id="user">
    Hello,
    <%=appUser.Name%>
    <span>►</span>
    <div>
        <a href="#">Change Password</a>
        <a href="#">Manage Security Questions</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

and the CSS for the element:

```
#user {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    padding: 2px;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #195d43;
    background-color: #f1f1ee;
}

#user:hover {
    background-color: #e1dfd9;
}

#user span {
    color: Silver;
}

#user div {
    display: none;
    background-color: #f1f1ee;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 999;
    border: solid 5px #e1dfd9;
}
```

**UPDATE 2:** This happens in Chrome. It does not happen in IE7. The app itself is MVC 1.0, VS 2008.

Comment: Your assumption is incorrect.  Please show a demo, or at least code.

Comment: Aye, put a test case up in jsfiddle and let us know browser and version.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem you are having is not that your hover code is being triggered, but that you are not initially hiding the menu in the css

```
#user div{display:none;}
```

Also, your selectors are screwy...

This...

```
$("span", "#user")
```

should be

```
$("span, #user")
```

**Here is a [working sample](http://jsfiddle.net/Jaybles/FQwts/)**

```
$("#user")
    .hover(
        function() {
            $("span, #user").css("color", "#195d43");
            $("#user div").show();
        },
        function() {
            $("span, #user").css("color", "#999");
            $("#user div").hide();
        }
);
```

Comment: That wouldn't explain why the background changes color, which is set via CSS (sorry, just added that part of the CSS to my question). Also, using ("span, #user") syntax will select all spans on the page and all #user elements. The ("span", "#user") syntax will select all spans under the #user element in the DOM.

Comment: Okay, I didn't realize that about the seconds part. Also in chrome, I see no background color change (http://jsfiddle.net/Jaybles/FQwts/9/)

Comment: I think the selector is actually supposed to be $('#user span') or, better, $('#user').find('span').

Comment: The background color change is subtle (slightly darker shade of gray), and I do see it happening in your jsfiddle example.

Comment: @Jed I tried this without the jQuery code altogether, and the background color still changes via CSS, so this is likely more of a Chrome issue than a jQuery issue.